# Read all tags and values from XML android java

Tags: java, android

I have been searching for reading XML tags and its values, what i can find is read the values using tag names, but without knowing the tag names is it possible to read all values, if so please explain me

**SAMPLE XML**

```
<menu>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>    
            <name>test1</name>
            <cost>155</cost>
            <description>Single</description>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <id>2</id>    
            <name>test2</name>
            <cost>225</cost>
            <description>double</description>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <id>3</id>    
            <name>test3</name>
            <cost>110</cost>
            <description>long</description>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <id>4</id>    
            <name>test4</name>
            <cost>155</cost>
            <description>float</description>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <id>5</id>    
            <name>test5</name>
            <cost>445</cost>
            <description>integer</description>
        </item> 

</menu>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What all values do you want to read?

Comment: All the tag names and the values inside tag names is it possible

Comment: Can you provide me any code sample please, like Node.getElementbyTagName("");

Comment: Please take a look at XMLPullParser - http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html
You can loop over all Tags and get the tag attributes and name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been tinkering with the same problem and think I have found the solution:

```
private void listNodes(NodeList nodeList){


    // Loop through the node list
    for (int temp = 0; temp < (nodeList != null ? nodeList.getLength() : 0); temp++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(temp);
        // if node is element
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            // create element from node
            Element element = (Element) node;

            // get tag name from element
            Log.d("tag", "tag/node: " + element.getTagName());

            // if node has children repeat the loop until last child
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {

                listNodes(node.getChildNodes());

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This will give you the tags of ALL nodes, now you just have to implement this to the desired level of your xml. Once you have the tags put them in an array and get elements from them.

**EDIT:**

ok so I've played with this for a while and got some interesting results. First of all I have my xmls set up so that each row is in an `<item>` tag so there is no confusion there. This is what I use to get the node list:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {

    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    // input stream of any kind, can be local or from URL
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    // rowNodeName in my case is "item" so you can change this to anything suitable
    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(rowNodeName);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

So now that you have the node list just do something like this:

```
// a global object for tag strings
nodeNames = new ArrayList<>();

// populate tag list by reading them from first element
listNodes(nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes(), false);

// list nodes, notice the second parameter is boolean
listNodes(nodeList,true);
```

And the final `listNodes` method is as follows:

```
private void listNodes(NodeList list, boolean getValues) {

    for (int temp = 0; temp < (list != null ? list.getLength() : 0); temp++) {

        Node node = list.item(temp);

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element element = (Element) node;

            // if you want values then you loop through the tag names and get node values for those tags
            if (getValues) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                for(int i = 0; i< nodeNames.size(); i++){

                    bundle.putString(nodeNames.get(i), getNode(nodeNames.get(i),element));

                }

                xmlTableRows.add(bundle);

            } else {
                /// if you want tags just read them from node
                nodeNames.add(element.getTagName());

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The `getNode` method:

```
private static String getNode(String tag, Element element) {

    NodeList nlList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();

}
```

So now you dont depend on knowing how many tags there are in an xml or what their names are. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory a = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); // Not Mandatory

    NodeList elements=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i=0; i<elements.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        // Get element
        Element elem = (Element)elements.item(i);
        System.out.println(elem.getNodeName());
    }
```